# By default, does Spring use the Factory Pattern?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, design-patterns

I've just read the Factory Pattern in the Head First Design Patterns Book. I'm just wondering if, by default, Spring uses this.

Let's say I have an AppConfigServiceImpl.java:

```
@Service("appConfigService")
public class AppConfigServiceImpl implements AppConfigService {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;
    @Autowired
    private IdGeneratorService idGeneratorService;

    @Override
    public void initializeUserId() {
        final Integer lastUserId = userService.getLastId();
        idGeneratorService.initialize(lastUserId);
    }
}
```

Isn't the AppConfigService a Factory Class Interface? And the AppConfigServiceImpl is the concrete class? And the initializeUserId() the factory method?

Or what if I have a structure like this:

```
public abstract class User 
public class AdminUser extends User
public class BusinessUser extends User

public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {
    @Override
    public User getUser(String userType) {
        if (UserType.ADMIN.toString.equalsIgnoreCase(userType)) {
            return new AdminUser();
        } else {
            return new BusinessUser();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that's not exactly a factory pattern.

As the name already says, a factory produces something. In software, a factory produces objects. So if you would like to have a `Car` instance, you might use a `CarFactory` to say:

```
Car myCar = CarFactory.produceACar();
```

That's the whole pattern. You have a class (the `CarFactory`) which encapsulates the production of an object (the `Car`). And it's important that the purpose of the class is to do this. Just returning an object is not enough to be a factory ;)

In your example, the method `UserServiceImpl#getUser` might a be some kind of a factory method as it returns different types of objects depending on the input. But not every method which return different things for different inputs are factories - almost every method will somehow do this.

In your example, you could create a `UserFactory` which your `UserServiceImpl` could use. You could create an `AdminUserFactory` (to create admins) and a `BusinessUserFactory` (to create business users). The `getUser` method would use both factories to get rid of the concrete instantiation mechanism for the objects.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see examples of Factory pattern implemented in Spring you should take a look at [FactoryBean](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/2.5.6/api/org/springframework/beans/factory/FactoryBean.html). It helps you to initialize bean with custom initialization logic. Also Spring provides capability to initialize bean using factory methods.
And, mainly, the whole Spring application context is a [BeanFactory](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/2.5.6/api/org/springframework/beans/factory/BeanFactory.html)

Answer (score 0):

Both are very different. And it's incorrect to say Spring uses FactoryPattern atleast for the service class you have mentioned in th1 1st code snippet.

Before going to logic understand the naming convention. `Service` is and interface and `ServiceImpl` is it's concrete implementation. Each service may have other h`elper services` or `daos`. When you talk about factory it is more of `utils` category since you expect various types of objects depending on input method you give to factory method.

So your 1st code snippet is a simple service class with some injected services and an overriden method. Nothing to do with factory pattern. Also each bean is `singleton` by default. The 2nd code snippet is a factory but has nothing related to Spring. Sure you may have autowired services in a factory class but again nothing that is a mandate and spring related.